# WPF ComboBox databinding help?

Tags: wpf-controls

I have a wpf combobox which I want to display a selection of strings

```
string[] list1= new string[]{"first","second"."third",fourth"} and so on
```

Xaml:

```
 ComboBox   Name="cmbItems"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=list1}"
 SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Display}"
```

where Display is the property in my ViewModel

```
    public string Display
    {

        get
        {
            return _Person.Display;
        }
        set
        {
            _Person.Display = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Display);
        }
    }
```

when i run my code..the combobox displays nothing....

can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the string array to public property.

private string[] list1 = new string[] { "first", "second", "third", "fourth" };

public string[] List1
  {
       get { return list1; }
       set { list1 = value; }
  }

Now bind to List1 (ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List1}")